# Mocking HttpContext.Current.ApplicationInstance.Response

Tags: unit-testing, moq

I'm using Nunit Unit testing framework and Moq for mocking the object in my MVC webapplication i have "HttpContext.Current.ApplicationInstance.Response"
in my action when testing that action which contains this code it returns error,
i have mocked the httpcontext already but i dont have idea about mocking applicationInstance.Response please help me guys

```
 public static Mock<HttpContextBase> HttpMock { get; set; }

    public void HttpContextMocking(string requesturl)
    {HttpMock = new Mock<HttpContextBase>();
        var fakeIdentity = new GenericIdentity("sampe@email.com");
        var principal = new GenericPrincipal(fakeIdentity, null);
        HttpMock.Setup(x => x.User).Returns(principal);
        HttpContext.Current = new HttpContext(new HttpRequest("", requesturl, ""), new HttpResponse(null));
        HttpContext.Current.User = principal;

        //Mocking the Httpcontext User Identity
        HttpMock.SetupGet(c => c.User.Identity.Name).Returns("sampe@email.com");}
```

Am Getting Error in the Nunit Application As Object Null reference execption, in that code in my source throws exception while debugging throw unit testing

"Response is not available in this context." 
HttpContext.Current.ApplicationInstance.Response = 'HttpContext.Current.ApplicationInstance.Response' threw an exception of type 'System.Web.HttpException'

Comment: What is the error that you are getting?

Comment: HI @VictorySaber i have updated The error in my question.

Comment: Your best option is to refactor your code so that the context (or even just the small piece of info you need off it) is a parameter, and then pass it in from something that you don't unit test. (You can still integration test it.) That would allow you to pass in a stub during unit testing. In the best case, your unit test gets reduced to a simple input/output test.

Comment: I unable to modify my source , any other solution for mocking httpContext.Current.Application ?

Comment: Don't unit test code you can't change. It's not a good use of time.

Comment: Yes, i know but i'm in situation to test the source which already developed and published web application so i dont have permission to  made changes in my source

Comment: Right, so you shouldn't unit test it. Unit testing is a task done during development. It's end goal is to increase reliability by helping you catch mistakes as you make changes and increase maintainability by pushing you toward a simpler system. Of course, unit testing isn't a silver bullet that magically does either of those; it still takes practice and skill and hard thinking and understanding to get those benefits. But you certainly won't get them if you're not modifying the code you're testing. The next time this code is changed is when you should consider adding tests; not before.

Comment: Obviously, that doesn't help if you're under some mandate to do so, but at least understand that you're being mandated to do something that's unproductive at best and will hamper future development at worst. On top of that, the code is in serious need of work if it's referencing [`HttpContext.Current`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.httpcontext.current%28v=vs.110%29.aspx). I think you're sunk, though. The type of that global is `sealed`, so I don't think you can mock it. You could try creating an instance and set the global, but heaven only knows if it'll work.

Answer (score 0):

Try to mock response:

```
var response1 = new Mock<HttpResponseBase>();
response1.Setup(p => p.Write(A<string>.Ignored)).Callback((string s) => sb.Append(s));
```

Comment: There are two different, unrelated `Response` types. The [one used by `HttpContext.Current`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.httpresponse%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) is sealed and does not inherit from `HttpResponseBase`. So this won't work for the OP's use case.